# Bootstrapping (symmetry breaking) in evolution

Tags: evolution, artificial-life

Many fascinating phenomena in nature show different behaviours on the micro and the macro level. Here I am especially referring to phenomena that are symmetric on the micro and asymmetric on the macro level. Let me give an examples from physics:

> [Arrow of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time): Physical processes at the micro level are
>   completely time-symmetric, if you reversed time, all laws would remain
>   the same. Yet on a macro level they are not time-symmetric, we have an
>   obvious direction (flow) of time.

It seems to me that we have a similar situation with evolution:

On the micro level it is really only about adaption (and not about improvement): You put some beings into an environment and they adapt, you change this environment and they adapt. No improvement, just blind "back and forth".

Yet looking at the whole tree of life on the macro level we have a different picture, we see all kinds of emergent phenomena:

- explosion in *diversity*
- emergence of complex interconnected *ecosystems* with completely new dynamics of their own
- true *innovations* in functionality (sensors, actuators, information processing etc.)
- and finally of course higher order functions like abstract *intelligence* (and  even *qualia*)

To make the difference more concrete I will give a *gedankenexperiment* of two planet simulators. In both cases you accelerate time so that one hour translates into one billion years. Both simulators function differently in a subtle way but you don't know how. You throw some simple sims onto both planets and let the evolution simulation run. You don't switch your computer off and go to bed, the next morning you decelerate time and take a look:

- Planet 1: The simple sims quickly adapted to the environment as expected (but they stayed simple because evolution is not about improvement but about adaption).
- Planet 2: Some strange looking sims wish you a good morning and want to discuss the technicalities of the Riemann hypothesis with you.

**My question**
What are the *minimal conditions* that have to be met to get this kind of bootstrapping (symmetry breaking from micro to macro level) started. And what is going on at the core of this transition from micro to macro.

**Edit**
My specific point is about the symmetry breaking process in the sense of system dynamics. To give an example of a possible answer it could be something like Parrondo's paradox, a fascinating phenomenon from game theory where you combine two symmetric (losing) processes to get a (winning) asymmetric process. More can be found here: [Parrondo's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrondo%27s_paradox).

Comment: This would require an entire book. There are several books on biochemical as well as mathematical explanation to how diversification could have happened. Most of our understanding is also incomplete. You have to ask a precise question or it is highly likely that this question would be closed for being too broad. Also, it is really essential for you to know some basic concepts of molecular biology, biochemistry and evolution.

Comment: I wish to reiterate that we are not being hostile towards you. Any good answer on this topic would require a good knowledge of biology. The issue with general evolution questions is that anyone who has read a popscience book comes up with a handwaving answer. **So, please focus on a specific point instead of asking how and why the world is as it is.**

Comment: @vonjd just because you produced an answer doesn't mean that the question itself isn't too broad, and I'm not even sure that it answers the question in a self-contained manner. You also need to stop ascribing motivations to people that may not have them, as many of your previous comments have done. This just makes other users less and less likely to answer your questions. No one on this site has a vendetta against you, but we all care about the quality and focus of this site, and so vote accordingly.

Comment: @WYSIWYG It is why SE has a voting system to promote good answers. Closing down questions for fear that they may attract bad answers seems to put the cart before the horse. I don't understand this kind of censorship. I won't even try to use the argument that anyone who doesn't like broad questions has no obligation to read this one.

Comment: Good well written questions would attract clear good quality answers - yours don't, they're consistently attracting junk. Anyone can turn up and vote on SE - they might know nothing about evolution, or (like me) might be an active researcher in the evolutionary biology community with a phd and masters degree in the subject... you should be more selective about whose voices you listen to if you want to learn.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky We are not censoring anything. I am just asking the OP to be precise. Broad questions are off-topic in any SE. Btw, I personally just pointed out to the OP that they should refine the question. I didn't close the question as you can see. Please go through the help center to know wat "broad questions" are.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34090/discussion-on-question-by-vonjd-bootstrapping-symmetry-breaking-in-evolution).

Comment: @WYSIWYG: Yes, you asked me to be precise and I therefore edited my question accordingly and asked for your feedback. I got no feedback but this comment was deleted. Then the question was over-hastily closed (not by you). That this question is *not* too broad can be seen by the fact that I gave a short and precise answer. Additionally people are giving precise answers in the comments. Now those answers have been moved to chat. I think there is something fundamentally going wrong in this community. I am active in many different SE communities and I have never encountered something like this :-(

Comment: @vonjd 1. **Comments are not used for answering** 2. **Your question is broad even after the edit** and if you think your own answer was what you were expecting then I don't think that is clear from the question. Please see MattDMo's comment. There is nothing wrong with this community; many people here also participate in other SEs. Vague and broad questions are not accepted in any SE. Perhaps you are better aware of other subjects so you don't end up asking vague questions in other SEs. None of your "supporters" are active here and probably even bio graduates. Your question is broad. Period.

Comment: Comments are moved to chat on other SEs all the time. They are also deleted as soon as they are not useful anymore all the time.

Comment: @vonjd THIS IS YELLING. **This is strong emphasis.** *This is emphasis.* WYSIWYG (who happens to be a site moderator, if you hadn't noticed the `♦` next to his username), was merely emphasizing SE rules, which are common across all sites, and which you appear to be selectively ignoring. That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a paper which gives four conditions that have to be met:

- Condition 1: A rule should be enforced that individuals
  must meet some minimal criterion (MC) before they
  can reproduce, and that criterion must be nontrivial
- Condition 2: The evolution of new individuals should
  create novel opportunities for satisfying the MC
- Condition 3: Decisions about how and where individuals
  interact with the world should be made by the individuals
  themselves
- Condition 4: The potential size and complexity of
  the individuals’ phenotypes should be (in principle) unbounded

Source: [Soros, Stanley (2014): Identifying Necessary Conditions for Open-Ended Evolution through the Artificial Life World of Chromaria](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/papers/soros_alife14.pdf)

[Chromaria](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/chromaria/home) is "an experimental platform that allows the exploration of evolutionary theories in an intuitive and visually engaging way" from EPLEX, the Evolutionary Complexity Research Group at the University of Central Florida (UCF)

Comment: Condition 2 does not have to be the case. Prokaryotes, single celled Eukaryotes, and some organism with fertile hermaphrodites more often than not create exact clones of themselves. Condition 3 does not happen in life. Even bacteria communicate chemically at a minimum creating quorum sensing behavior within the colony. Condition 4 doesn't hold for life as most organisms will operate at some optimal level. They will lose traits that are not used, especially those that are not required for survival.

Comment: @vonjd "Later I found that it is still a huge research topic to find out what we are missing (keyword: "open-ended evolution")" You are still misstating this - it's not that we are missing big chunks of information about how *evolution* works, algorithms *simulating evolution* are missing a lot. That's what people have been trying to tell you.

Comment: @YviDe: I get that but how can you be so sure without even be willing to think about it? It is as though you thought you knew everything about aerodynamics and when you build a plane it instantly stalls in the air and crashes. You did everything according to the theory of aerodynamics. Then you ask the aerodynamics experts and they tell you: "No, no, we know everything. We don't know why your plane crashed but our theory is complete. It must be your fault and we don't want to think nor talk about it - case closed." Would you accept that? I don't - and I don't think it is good science either.

Comment: @vonjd you seem to be completely comfortable just taking the other view, though, that Biologists must be missing something that's "breaking symmetry". As for why I am comfortable saying that the fault is in the models and not in our understanding - because I actually used to study Evolutionary Bioinformatics (MSc) and we acknowledged that we lacked computer power to model everything when doing simulations.

Comment: @YviDe: NB: I am talking about the *first* plane ever built. If you built a plane today and it crashes it is of course an engineering problem not a problem with the theory. But in evolution despite decades of research we are still far from producing anything that faintly resembles *real* evolution. So, yes, you could be right but the case is far from closed. The evidence that evolution happened on this planet is overwhelming but the argument that we understand the whole process sufficiently well is far from conclusive.

Comment: It's called Occam's razor. We **know** our simulations are lacking, so if they don't produce the desired result we need to first look at our models and computations to find the fault, and only if we can exclude that (which we can't) should we look at the theory behind the simulations.

Comment: @YviDe: "we lacked computer power to model everything when doing simulations" - this could be true too. But it can also be the case that we miss something fundamentally different. That we do the abstractions at the wrong places. I mean we are able to simulate the creation of galaxies in the early universe because we know how to simplify the model enough to get to the bottom of things. If you wanted to simulate that with every single atom involved you would also lack the computing power. We have not yet understood what a good simplification/abstraction of evolution could look like.

Comment: @YviDe: and e.g. one of my master students is working on a multi-agent simulation of the stock market at the moment. This model is able to reproduce many important stylized facts of markets. And, believe me, markets are also very, very complicated beasts. People could tell you that you had to simulate millions of brains that are involved in the process - but that of course misses the point. All models are wrong, some are useful: We have not yet found the right abstract model (from an algorithmics point of view) of *real* evolution that does just the simplifications at the right places.

Comment: @vonjd If you want to ask about a right model to simulate the evolutionary process then your question should have these: 1. **Kind of outcomes do you expect** (i.e what exactly you are looking for) 2. **The scale of the model** 3. **Assumptions you can allow** 4. **Kind of model (deterministic or stochastic)** 5. **Computational resource available** (optional).
You should explain what you have thought of and then ask. You should also go through the existing algorithms. If you are unaware of those then your question should be a reference request asking for papers on evolutionary simulations.

Comment: @vonjd "This model is able to reproduce many important stylized facts of markets." And if it didn't, would your first question be "what are we missing about the workings of the stock market" or would it be "let me look at that model and see how good your model is"?

Comment: As it was, your first question was "What are we missing about the real workings of the evolutionary process?" which is still about what we are missing about the actual process, not the simulations - turns out, even from your own research into the topic, that that question was based on wrong assumptions. See the paper you referenced in that other question and how they talk about porevious work done on the subject. "If we cannot simulate a process we have not understood it properly" is wrong - we might actually be simulating what we know badly.

Comment: @vonjd As for why you got such a strong response, I am guessing it's because our inability to simulate evolution well has led to it being used as an argument against evolution again and again. See, for example http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/40845/do-the-claims-in-this-paper-have-any-degree-of-validity

Comment: I've removed the comments that focused on persons, and not on the post and the content. Criticism is welcome, but please keep it constructive.